# Does anybody here ever do sound for motion graphics?

Tags: design

Does anybody here ever do sound for motion graphics? 
Stuff for 3d artists like website...http://www.mographwiki.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I see we are starting to get some fishermen dipping their rods into our little backwater. Interesting.  Could be good, could be bad. Either way I don't suppose there's any way to stop it.

I've done a little bit here and there, mostly for fun to be frank. I did a couple quick things for my cousin a while back. I really enjoy them. You can get a little weirder than usual. Plus, they're short, sweet, and you get the quick hit of doing something awesome in about 5 hours.

I had a couple MG guys whose work I was following for a while (their sound designers were really good too), but they both dried up about 6 months ago. I assume they either got corporate gigs, or decided to get "real" jobs.

I have no idea if it's a viable market to really focus on, seems like most companies are happy to either have their video editor slap something together, or just leave it blank. But then again, if you're persuasive/good enough I'd bet there're tons of CG school grads and little production companies who'd throw you a bill or two to spice up their visuals.

Do you have something coming up, or are you just asking out of interest?

Comment: /well a friend from the school i went to finished a project in motion graphics…i dint't know what the stuff was called until after i saw his project..it was copied sound design and i'm interested in the freedom of motion graphic sound design and plan on investigating it a little..the combination of unique video with unique sound makes an odd beauty mark on the perception of my impermanent universe


Comment: and I like to drink PBR

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my team specializes in that you can see our work at www.fntv.com. If you are looking for someone to do sound design for MG feel free to contact me at pete@claymorepictures.com we'll hook you up.

Answer (score 0):

yup - http://www.CypherAudio.com

Answer (score 0):

Like many other here, I've done some too, but the platform for motion graphics don't usually call for audio unless it's a tvc. I find most of them are generally quite happy using a piece of music as a guide track for their work.

Answer (score 0):

For the people that do this stuff regularly, I've always kind of wondered...what types of things do you do to create these abstract sounds? Care to share any techniques?